# python program not starting debug in progress

Tags: python, debugging, pyscripter

i`m very new to python and programming overall and i got my homework task to write a program on python 2.7 pyscripter. once i wrote the program i hit run and it asked me for user input. after that nothing happened and it says debugging in progress. i have waited but nothing happened.
heres the code:

```
in_balance = float(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card"))
int_rate = float(raw_input('Annual interest rate as decimal'))
min_month_pay = 0
month_int_rate = int_rate/12
month = 0
balance = in_balance

while balance > 0:
    month = 0
    balance = in_balance
    min_month_pay = min_month_pay + 10
    while month < 12 and balance > 0:
        month = month + 1
        interest = month_int_rate * balance
        balance = balance + interest
balance = round(balance, 2)
print 'result'
print 'month pay to pay off in 1 year: $', min_month_pay
print 'number of months needed: ', month
print 'Balance: $', balance
```

Comment: Your outer `while` loop resets `balance` to `in_balance` in every iteration. So it appears it will never exit that loop. And I don't see anything that will reduce `balance` to less than zero to exit the loop. Are you forgetting to make payments on your balance?

Comment: ohh, so it will say debugging if its stuck in infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

As bogatron said, you have an infinite loop, as long as in_balance > 0. I'm not familiar with pyscripter, but if it's like any other debugger, it will say "debugging" if it's executing any code. If you had paused t, you would have seen it stop at one of the lines in your while loop. Not sure what the attempted functionality is, but I'm not sure why you have the while loop to begin with, since balance will never decrease even if it wasn't being reassigned each time.